# OAF How to align fields

Tags: oaf

When I put several fields under the element with type "header", the fields are misaligned. I need their left sides aligned.

[image: misaligned]

Answer (score 0):

Alignment is supported if you put the fields under "MessageComponentLayout" type parent. However, once you do this, the whole block will move to the center of the screen (see the image, example 2). To fix it, go to the parent properties and set them as following (see the image, example 3):

- Width: 1%
- Rows: 1
- Columns: 1

There is another hack. You can set rows and columns properties for larger values and programmatically insert empty text fields after of before you target fields. If you insert them after, target fields will move to the left and vice versa. The drawback of this hack is that at the moment of rendering you can see how target fields are moving from the center to the side of the screen.

[image: Aligned]